# 'ContentMode' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am running my project with Xcode 10 but there is this issue:

> 'ContentMode' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

on the following line of code:

```
@objc open var imageContentMode: ContentMode = .aspectFill
```

in `open class ImageScrollView: UIScrollView` class

Comment: Set it to `@objc open var imageContentMode: UIView.ContentMode = .aspectFill`?

Comment: Did you import `UIKit`?

Comment: yes, I imported.